# EJB lookup from Play application

Tags: ejb, playframework-2.0, glassfish-3, jndi

I have a Play application (I am using Play 2.1.0) from which I would like to invoke EJBs running on a GlassFish server. Therefore, I have tried adding gf-client.jar as a dependency in my Play application and getting a reference to the EJBs the same way I would do in a standalone application:

```
Hashtable<String, String> properties = new Hashtable<String, String>();
properties.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory");
properties.put("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "com.sun.enterprise.naming");
properties.put("java.naming.factory.state", "com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl");
properties.put("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "localhost");
properties.put("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");
properties.put("java.naming.provider.url", "iiop://localhost:3700");
Context ctx = new InitialContext(properties);
ctx.lookup("java:global/MyApplication/MyEJB/MyBean");
```

I get however the following exception when executing the lookup:

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[RuntimeException: javax.naming.NotContextException: global is not a subcontext]]
        at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:289) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
        at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:383) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anon$2$$anonfun$handle$1.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:132) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anon$2$$anonfun$handle$1.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:128) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
        at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
        at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NotContextException: global is not a subcontext
        at play.libs.F$Promise$6.apply(F.java:401) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.liftedTree2$1(Future.scala:253) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:249) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:249) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:29) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.liftedTree1$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:67) ~[akka-actor_2.10.jar:na]
Caused by: javax.naming.NotContextException: global is not a subcontext
        at tyrex.naming.EnvContext.internalLookup(Unknown Source) ~[tyrex.jar:1.0.1  November 11 2003 1703]
        at tyrex.naming.EnvContext.lookup(Unknown Source) ~[tyrex.jar:1.0.1  November 11 2003 1703]
        at tyrex.naming.java.JavaContext.lookup(Unknown Source) ~[tyrex.jar:1.0.1  November 11 2003 1703]
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411) ~[na:1.7.0_10]
        at controllers.Application.index(Application.java:36) ~[na:na]
        at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(routes_routing.scala:77) ~[na:na]
```

The exact same code with the same gf-client.jar dependency works fine from a standalone application.
The fact that what I actually get is a NotContextException and that in the exception stacktrace I see the following line

```
at tyrex.naming.EnvContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
```

leads me to believe that for some reason the InitialContext I am getting is not "correct", since the stacktrace I get in my standalone application if I specify a JNDI name that does not exist is a bit different:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:global/Test/MyBean' in SerialContext[myEnv={org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort=3700, java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory, org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost=localhost, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Test]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:518)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:455)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at com.eurodyn.testmavenjavaapp.App.main(App.java:24)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Test
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.resolveContext(TransientContext.java:310)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:218)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:219)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:77)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.RemoteSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(RemoteSerialContextProviderImpl.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie.dispatchToMethod(ReflectiveTie.java:144)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie._invoke(ReflectiveTie.java:174)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:528)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:199)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1624)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1486)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:990)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:214)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:742)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.doWork(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:2324)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there some other way to perform JNDI lookup from a Play application? I understand from [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819137/java-ee-architecture-with-play-framework/8822210#answer-8822210) that this is something that can be done.

Comment: gf-client.jar refers to many other jars so it is best to refer to GlassFish directory so that it gets all the required jars. GlassFish outputs EJB JNDI names in logs please check the name in the log

Comment: @Abdullah Shaikh Is this possible in a Play application? As far as I know the only way to add dependencies are either from a Maven repository (the method I have used) or by copying jars in the lib folder of my application, which would mean that I would have to move the jar from its original location anyway. And what if I had a remote GlassFish running on another machine? In that case I wouldn't even have access to the GlassFish installation directory.

Comment: Your lookup name is "java:global/MyBean", it should of the form java:global/your application name/ejb module/bean name or java:global/ejb module/bean name incase the ejb module is outside ear

Comment: @Abdullah Shaikh I had just entered it as java:global/MyBean in my post for simplicity, in fact I use the exact name I get from GlassFish when the EJB is deployed, which is of course of the form you mention. I also updated my post to make that more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this problem for me (Play 2.1.3 and Glassfish 3.1.2.2) by adding the gf-client-module to the dependencies in the project/Build.scala instead of trying to link the jar directly:

```
"org.glassfish.main.appclient.client" % "gf-client-module" % "3.1.2.2"
```

When resolving the dependencies it missed the module org.eclipse.persistence#javax.persistence;2.0.4.v201112200901 which I was able to locate here:

```
 resolvers += "opencastproject" at "http://repository.opencastproject.org/nexus/content/groups/public/"
```

To be sure what name to lookup I checked the names availabe in that context:

```
InitialContext ic = getInitialContext();
System.out.println(ic.getEnvironment());
NamingEnumeration<NameClassPair> childList = ic.list("");
while (childList.hasMore()) {
NameClassPair ncPair = (NameClassPair) childList.next();
    if (ncPair.getName().contains("Job") == false) {
        System.out.println(ncPair.getName() + " (type " + ncPair.getClassName() + ")");
    }
}
```

I used the names exactly as the were listed there.

Regards